How to install @types/node by docker RUN inside Dockerfile
When I use the following Dockerfile:
FROM node:22-alpine

ENV NODE_ENV production

WORKDIR /usr/web-server

RUN npm i -g @nestjs/cli typescript

COPY ./package*.json ./

RUN npm install
RUN npm install @types/node

COPY ./ ./

EXPOSE 4000

CMD npm run start:dev

inside /usr/web-server/node_modules/@types node folder not installed.
However, if I use the Dockerfile below:
FROM node:22-alpine

ENV NODE_ENV production

WORKDIR /usr/web-server

RUN npm i -g @nestjs/cli typescript

COPY ./package*.json ./
RUN npm install
RUN npm uninstall @types/node
RUN npm install @types/node

COPY ./ ./

EXPOSE 4000

CMD npm run start:dev

everything works fine.
Why in first Dockerfile RUN npm install @types/node doesn't install node folder inside @types?
I try to RUN npm install @types/node after COPY ./ ./ but it doesn't work either

Please edit your post and add information on how you run your container and how you check if the module is installed. My guess is that you run your container with a volume mapping on /usr/web-server which hides all the files in the image.

Should this package be included in the devDependencies section of your package.json?

I this case it doesn't work in the first Dockerfile because @type/node was installed like dev dependency in package.json
"devDependencies": {
   "@types/node": "^20.12.12",
}

When i install it like RUN npm install @types/node inside Dockerfile, it doesn't add node folder inside @types in node_modules, because @types/node not istalled if it like devDependeces package.
When jumping into the Docker container:
cd /usr/web-server/node_modules/@types
ls 
// result empty folder

However, when i uninstall it and install it again as main dependency, it work fine:
cd /usr/web-server/node_modules/@types
ls 
// Now result is node folder

thats why the second Docker file is worked fine
and if i add packege @type/node like main dependence in package.json file:
"dependencies": {
   "@types/node": "^20.12.12",
}

Now I dont need to add RUN npm install/unistall @types/node in Dockerfile.
The remaining question is why @types/node is not installed in the container as a devDependency, but that's another issue already.

Are you sure that you don't have a conflicting version of @types/node specified in your package.json? Suppose, for example, that you had this specified in package.json:
"@types/node": "^16.0.0"

Install from Dockerfile
Something like this will enable you to install from the Dockerfile without first uninstalling.
 Dockerfile
FROM node:22-alpine

ENV NODE_ENV production

WORKDIR /usr/web-server

RUN npm i -g @nestjs/cli typescript

COPY ./package*.json ./
RUN npm install
RUN npm install @types/node

COPY ./ ./

EXPOSE 4000

CMD npm run start:dev

 package.json (Note that this doesn't contain @types/node, @nestjs/cli or typescript, all of which are being installed from the Dockerfile!)
  "name": "nestjs-web-server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A simple NestJS web server",
  "main": "src/main.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^9.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/testing": "^9.0.0",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "eslint": "^8.15.0",
    "jest": "^29.0.0"
  }
}

Install from package.json
IMHO a better option is to move the package installation completely to package.json. With the setup below all packages are installed in a single npm install command.
 Dockerfile
FROM node:22-alpine

ENV NODE_ENV production

WORKDIR /usr/web-server

COPY ./package*.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY ./ ./

EXPOSE 4000

CMD npm run start:dev

 package.json
{
  "name": "nestjs-web-server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A simple NestJS web server",
  "main": "src/main.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "start:dev": "npx nest start --watch"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/cli": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^9.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/testing": "^9.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^20.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "eslint": "^8.15.0",
    "jest": "^29.0.0"
  }
}

